# jQueryMobile stopping page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app that's using the jquerymobile fb swipe method, dunno where it's located to show the original. However. My biggest problem is that it takes a link and dynamically tries to load the page via an ajax get method of some sort. Which is not what I want; I want to have the page load like a normal link was clicked on any other site, but I dunno how to disable it, the docs make it seem like it's possible, but I'm not sure myself.

This is the only custom JS as far as I can tell thats part of this template

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
});



        $(function(){
            var menuStatus;


            // Show menu
            $("a.showMenu").click(function(){
                if(menuStatus != true){             
                $(".ui-page-active").animate({
                    marginLeft: "175px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
                  return false;
                  } else {
                    $(".ui-page-active").animate({
                    marginLeft: "0px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
                    return false;
                  }
            });


            $('#menu, .pages').live("swipeleft", function(){
                if (menuStatus){    
                $(".ui-page-active").animate({
                    marginLeft: "0px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
                  }
            });

            $('.pages').live("swiperight", function(){
                if (!menuStatus){   
                $(".ui-page-active").animate({
                    marginLeft: "175px",
                  }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
                  }
            });

            $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
                menuStatus = false;
                $(".pages").css("margin-left","0");
            });

            // Menu behaviour
            $("#menu li a").click(function(){
                var p = $(this).parent();
                if($(p).hasClass('active')){
                    $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
                    $(p).addClass('active');
                }
            });

            $("#b_done").click(function(){
                $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
                $("#menu li:first-child").addClass('active');
            });

            // Tabs 
            $('div[data-role="navbar"] a').live('click', function () {
                $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
                $('div.content_div').hide();
                alert($(this).attr('data-href'));
                //$('div#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
                //window.location = $(this).attr.('data-href');
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off Ajax loading in the mobile init

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
     $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unable to find any particular code which changes page in jquery mobile.

Have a look at jquery mobile ajax behavior documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Usually to load page/html without Ajax,
either put rel=external or put data-ajax=false in your Anchor tag .

like

```
<a href="/anotherPage" rel='external'>
```